# why dash didn't show up with list-packages

Tags: package, dash.el

I was trying to install dash using elpa but failed.

I can't understand why it shows `dash[no match]` by following `M-x package-install RET dash RET` as in the snapshot. can anyone let me know why? Thank you!

I also tried list-package and dash does not show up in the available list. I am pretty sure I installed dash this way earlier and removed it later.

I described the package-archives variable and it's as below:

```
package-archives is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.
Its value is
(("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")
 ("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("melpa" . "https://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
Original value was 
(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure dash.el isn't already installed? `M-x package-install` doesn't show installed packages.

Comment: Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32702754/adding-package-repositories-to-emacs)  and run `package-refresh-contents`. Run `M-x package-install` and `dash` still does not show up in the auto-complete list. Then run `M-x list-packages` and it shows indeed `dash` is installed. @xuchunyang, you are right and thank you! But what I don't understand is why `dash` didn't even show up by running `M-x list-packages` previously.

Comment: Based on your comment, please consider *changing your question* to ask only that: why `dash` didn't show up with `list-packages`.